# best way to get changed location iPhone sdk?

Tags: iphone, sdk

**My ultimate goal is that i need to send lat and logitude to web server, every time when location changes.**

I am using below code for sending lat and longitude of a device to a web server after every 2 minutes but it is not giving sometimes correct latitude and longitude as location changes.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation
 *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSTimeInterval locationAge = -[newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow];
    NSLog(@"Location Age%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",locationAge]);
    if (locationAge > 5) return;

    // test that the horizontal accuracy does not indicate an invalid measurement    
    if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0) return;

    NSString *stringUrl;
   // BOOL check = FALSE;
    NSLog(@"Before condition condition");
    if(bestEffortAtLocation == nil || bestEffortAtLocation.horizontalAccuracy > newLocation.horizontalAccuracy){
        NSLog(@"condition");
         self.bestEffortAtLocation = newLocation;

        if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy <= locmanager.desiredAccuracy) {
            // we have a measurement that meets our requirements, so we can stop updating the location
            // IMPORTANT!!! Minimize power usage by stopping the location manager as soon as possible.
            [locmanager stopUpdatingLocation];
            locmanager.delegate = nil;
        }
        //check = TRUE;
    }

    stringUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:URLSAVELAT,stringUserId,[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g",self.bestEffortAtLocation.coordinate.latitude],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g",self.bestEffortAtLocation.coordinate.longitude]];}
```

**For location manager i am using below code**

```
{
 locmanager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
 [locmanager setDelegate:self];
 locmanager.distanceFilter = 10.0;
 //locmanager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
 [locmanager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
 [locmanager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Any,even small help would be appreciated, Thank u in advance

Comment: One thing that may be causing a problem is that the gps data given to the iPhone is not very accurate. When I used it, I was sometimes getting values that changed by about 50-100 meters while I was standing still (although, this wasn't on every update). This might be what is causing your problem. If you need to be really accurate, you may have to use the compass and gyro to simulate the movement of the device in the real world, and compare it to gps data to make a better estimate on the actual movement. Hope that helps!

Comment: can you provide me any source or reference for this, to use this functionality for location tracking.

Comment: Apparently, in iOS 4.0 and higher, you can now use the constant kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation for higher accuracy, although it does mention that it should be used when the device is plugged in. It can be found here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationConstantsRef/Reference/reference.html

Answer (score 3):

You should use the location update call backs from the API and use updateLocation method:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
if([self.delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(CoreLocationControllerDelegate)]) {
    [self.delegate locationUpdate:newLocation];
}
}
```

Then in the viewcontroller do this:

```
- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location {

//DO WHATEVER YOU WANT HERE, INCLUDING SENDING TO SERVER

}
```

You also need to define two protocol methods, one of which is the locationUpdate:

```
 @protocol CoreLocationControllerDelegate
@required

- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location;
- (void)locationError:(NSError *)error;

@end
```

I would not recommend doing all that you do in the didUpdateLocation: method.